# Get path folder in URL with PHP

Tags: php, url

I use this PHP code for find the url path of a script page :

```
define("URL", dirname($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
```

On my PC 1, I get this result with this url : htt://site1/abc/ :

```
/abc
```

but on my PC 2, I get this result with the same URL :

```
\
```

Don't understand why. If i add 'index.php', that's ok on PC 2

My goal is create a wizard installation and put the url path in the config file.

Comment: I'm going to take a wild guess, ones a unix box and ones a windows box?

Comment: No, PC 1and 2 are on Win 7 with EasyPhp 14.1VC9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may get unexpected results with [`dirname()`](http://hu1.php.net/dirname), see the example in the manual:

```
echo "2) " . dirname("/etc/") . PHP_EOL; // 2) / (or \ on Windows)
```

Use [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) instead:

```
$path = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
$path = '/'.implode('/', explode('/', ltrim($path, '/'), -1));
define("URL", $path);
```

Comment: I get '/' on PC 1 instead of /abc

Comment: @Portekoi Updated the code, can you please try again?